# How can I use Javascript or Jquery to close accordion on page load (Wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When opening the page at https://bluegrassomnimedia.com/kawneer/, the first accordion item is open. I am wanting the item to be closed on the initial page load with no accordion content showing. Here is the JQuery code that I have placed in the header:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

Additionally, here is JS code that I have tried:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
  var el = elements[i];      
  el.setAttribute( "class", el.getAttribute("class") + "" );
}
```

When an "li" item is chosen or displayed, it is assigned the class "active". I am simply trying to load the page without the first li having the class. What am I doing wrong? (Fairly new to WP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out this line:

```
jQuery('.accordion li:first-child').addClass('active');
```

This can be located in:
wp-content/themes/partner/styles/js/scripts.js

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Could you tell me how you were able to pinpoint the location of the script and the line to comment out?

Comment: Sure. I opened up Chrome dev tools and did a search for 'accordion' in the Network tab. I noticed the 'addClass' method was being applied to the accordion, clicked on that and found it.